# Python: Conditional sum of rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Here is the logic that I'm trying to implement: Where exchange, ticker and year match, sum div_amt into a new column called annual_div. I'm importing the data from a CSV and doing the following:

```
# Change to datetime format
ZACKS_DH_df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(ZACKS_DH_df['div_ex_date']).dt.year

# Sum annual dividend
ZACKS_DH_df['annual_div'] = ZACKS_DH_df.groupby('exchange' and 'ticker' and 'year').sum()['div_amt']
```

I've included a screenshot of the output I am getting. As you can see I am getting NaN in the annual_div column. I've tried lots of variations but with no success.

I'd be happy with either:

1. The annual_div being the sum of the div_amt where exchange, ticker and year match, and that annual_div figure be replicated for each of the contributing rows.
2. Create a new dataframe which keeps all columns except the div_amt and div_ex_date so that there is just one row per ticker per year.

[image]

Comment: I think you need `ZACKS_DH_df['annual_div'] = ZACKS_DH_df.groupby(['exchange', 'ticker' , 'year'])['div_amt'].transform(sum)`, it is dupe :(

Comment: Thank you so much, this works. While similar questions had been asked before, I had not seen an answer with 'transform' in it. That got it going. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome! Nice day!